# Resolve rtld(GNU_HASH) dependency in yum

Tags: php, bash, yum

I'm trying to install a package but can't seem to complete the process. I receive the following error when I attempt to install...

```
Error: Missing Dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by package newrelic-php5
```

I'm trying to install the new relic application monitor, I don't know if that is the culprit but I would assume from the looks of the error that the dependency is a generic one. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: Distribution and glibc version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the current version of New Relic cannot be installed on CentOS 4.8 (and probably anything in the 4.x arm). It might be possible to update the libraries and stay within the 4.x arm but it would be difficult and probably very buggy. GLIBC is apparently the culprit as the 2.2 series does not have the same support for POSIX threads that the 2.3.x versions do.

Answer (score 2):

You need a newer version of libdl (part of glibc) that has the GNU_HASH feature. Objects built with binutils 2.17+ will have this enabled. So, if your system has a lower version of binutils, your glibc was likely built without it too. (In other words, you may simply need a newer distro if you want to get this fixed.)

Comment: I think that is going to set me on the right path. I ran ld -v and it appears that it (as well as the other program 'as') both return 2.15 as a version. I'll assume that the binutils version used to build them was 2.15. Sorry to be a newb but I'll need to install the newest version of binutils (2.21) and then I should be good to go?

Comment: I've upgraded my binutils to 2.21 but am still getting the GNU_HASH error, how do I know what version of libdl I am running? Is there a way to tell if GNU_HASH is in a given version?

Comment: I'm also running CentOS 4.8, do I need to upgrade to 5?